# Shell Script won't fail in Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, jenkins, return-value

I have a simple shell script which I want to set up as a periodic Jenkins job rather than a cronjob for visibility and usability for less experienced users.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
outputfile=/opt/jhc/streaming/check_error_output.txt

if [ "grep -sq 'Unable' $outputfile" == "0" ]; then
    echo -e "ERROR MESSAGE FOUND\n"
    exit 1
else
    echo -e "NO ERROR MESSAGES HAVE BEEN FOUND\n"
    exit 0
fi
```

My script will always return "NO ERROR MESSAGES HAVE BEEN FOUND" regardless of whether or not 'Unable' is in $outputfile, what am I doing wrong?

I also need my Jenkins job to class this as a success if 'Unable' isn't found (e.g. If script returns "0" then pass, everything else is fail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the grep command and check the exit status instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
outputfile=/opt/jhc/streaming/check_error_output.txt
grep -sq 'Unable' $outputfile
if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
    echo -e "ERROR MESSAGE FOUND\n"
    exit 1
else
    echo -e "NO ERROR MESSAGES HAVE BEEN FOUND\n"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: You the man! I should've thought of this myself, I've been staring at it for too long, my head has gone

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two different strings. The outcome will always be false, i.e. the else part is taken.

Also, no need to explicitly query the status code. Do it like this:

```
if grep -sq 'Unable' $outputfile
then
  ....
else
  ....
fi
```

Comment: This is the way I started out initially, except I had my grep command in '[ ]'